# How to parse strings from a file in multiple other files?

Tags: awk, command-line, grep

I am trying to grep a list of strings listed in 7253.txt which looks like this:

```
rs11078372 
rs1124961 
rs11651880 
rs11659047 
rs1736209
```

using:

```
grep -o -f 7253.txt *.logistic > result.txt
```

from multiple files *.logistic. The files are on larger size and this grep command takes forever.

.logistic files look like this:

```
#CHROM  POS  ID REF ALT A1  TEST    OBS_CT  OR  LOG(OR)_SE  Z_STAT  P
17  16933404    rs11867934  T   C   T   ADD 32232   0.974082    0.0279353   -0.940008   0.347213
```

so the strings from 7253.txt are matched from ID column in .logistic. And they should be the exact match.

Do you have more efficient way to parse those *.logistic files?

There is 22 of these files, and they are named like:FINchr1.pheno.glm.logistic, FINchr2.pheno.glm.logistic...

It would be great if I can have in result.txt extracted columns from .logistic for ID and P (3rd and 12th column)

To extract only ID from .logistic I could do this:

```
awk 'FNR!=1 {print $3}' *.logistic | grep -o -w -F -f 7253.txt > result.txt
```

But how to extract ID and P column, which are 3rd and 12th column in .logistic

Thanks
Ana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {ids[$1]=1; next}
    $3 in ids {print $3, $12}
' 7253.txt *.logistic > result.txt
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!